# Reading *.mhd/*.raw format in python

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, image-processing, computer-vision

Can anyone please tell me the way I can read a dataset containing *.mhd/*.raw files in python?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The easiest way is to use [SimpleITK](http://www.simpleitk.org) (MedPy uses ITK for .mhd/.raw files too). Command

```
pip install SimpleITK
```

works for many python versions. For reading .mhd/.raw you can use this code [from kaggle](https://www.kaggle.com/arnavkj95/data-science-bowl-2017/candidate-generation-and-luna16-preprocessing/run/973430)

```
import SimpleITK as sitk
import numpy as np
'''
This funciton reads a '.mhd' file using SimpleITK and return the image array, origin and spacing of the image.
'''

def load_itk(filename):
    # Reads the image using SimpleITK
    itkimage = sitk.ReadImage(filename)

    # Convert the image to a  numpy array first and then shuffle the dimensions to get axis in the order z,y,x
    ct_scan = sitk.GetArrayFromImage(itkimage)

    # Read the origin of the ct_scan, will be used to convert the coordinates from world to voxel and vice versa.
    origin = np.array(list(reversed(itkimage.GetOrigin())))

    # Read the spacing along each dimension
    spacing = np.array(list(reversed(itkimage.GetSpacing())))

    return ct_scan, origin, spacing
```

Comment: BTW, [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37989196/how-do-i-open-mhd-file-corresponding-to-a-raw-file-in-blender-3d-tool) question is same. Can someone merge them?

Comment: no but you can mark as duplicate if you think they are duplicates

Comment: Just a note for anyone using this solution: The numpy array returned by `sitk.GetArrayFromImage(itkimage)` has its coordinates in backwards order, flipping x and z. You would index it like this: `ct_scan[z,y,x]`. Very important!

Answer (score 12):

Using skimage may be even easier after you installed SimpleITK

```
import skimage.io as io
img = io.imread('file.mhd', plugin='simpleitk')
```

This will give you a numpy array with z,y,x sorting.

Comment: What about the metadata? the information in mhd is important.

Answer (score 6):

Adding on the above posts, you can start with a CT-Scan .mhd file downloaded from the [here](http://www.insight-journal.org/rire/) and display / save 29 images with the following code (assuming that you have both the header and the raw files downloaded in the current directory):

```
import SimpleITK as sitk
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
ct_scans = sitk.GetArrayFromImage(sitk.ReadImage("training_001_ct.mhd", sitk.sitkFloat32))
plt.figure(figsize=(20,16))
plt.gray()
plt.subplots_adjust(0,0,1,1,0.01,0.01)
for i in range(ct_scans.shape[0]):
    plt.subplot(5,6,i+1), plt.imshow(ct_scans[i]), plt.axis('off')
    # use plt.savefig(...) here if you want to save the images as .jpg, e.g.,
plt.show()
```

[image]

Here is the same CT-scan .mhd file that is read with `SimpleITK` and animated:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use [MedPy](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/MedPy) or this [mhd_utils script](https://github.com/yanlend/mhd_utils/blob/master/mhd_utils.py)