# Error reading mhd files with SimpleITK in Python

Tags: python, image-processing, computer-vision, itk, simpleitk

I'm here again with another question regarding SimpleITK in python. I want to plot a .mhd image but I don't know how. I'm  trying the function described here [Reading *.mhd/*.raw format in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37290631/reading-mhd-raw-format-in-python):

```
load_itk('/home/bianca/Documents/PythonProcessing/result-Edep.mhd')
```

But it is not reading the image:

```
RuntimeError: Exception thrown in SimpleITK ReadImage: /tmp/SimpleITK-build/ITK/Modules/IO/Meta/src/itkMetaImageIO.cxx:483:
itk::ERROR: MetaImageIO(0x3a83730): File cannot be read: /home/bianca/Documents/PythonProcessing/result-Edep.mhd for reading.
Reason: Success
```

I have tried with scikit image too...

```
img = io.imread('/home/bianca/Documents/PythonProcessing/result-Edep.mhd', plugin='simpleitk')
```

but I'm also getting an error message

```
RuntimeError: Exception thrown in SimpleITK ReadImage: /tmp/SimpleITK-build/ITK/Modules/IO/Meta/src/itkMetaImageIO.cxx:483:
itk::ERROR: MetaImageIO(0x3a84280): File cannot be read: /home/bianca/Documents/PythonProcessing/result-Edep.mhd for reading.
Reason: Success
```

Even with medpy

```
from medpy.io import load
image_data, image_header = load('/home/bianca/Documents/PythonProcessing/result-Edep.mhd')

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#17>", line 1, in <module>
    image_data, image_header = load('/home/bianca/Documents/PythonProcessing/result-Edep.mhd')
  File "medpy/io/load.py", line 201, in load
    raise err
DependencyError: Loading images of type Itk/Vtk MetaImage (.mhd, .mha/.raw) requires a third-party module that could not be encountered. Reason: No module named itk.
```

But I do have SimpleITK now. I don't understand what's going on... =(

Answer (score 1):

Is the file you are trying to read valid? You can check that using some other image displaying tool, e.g. [ITK-SNAP](http://www.itksnap.org/) or [3D Slicer](https://www.slicer.org/). If either of these tools can open it, please tell us the version of SimpleITK you are using.

Comment: MHD Files typically require an mhd header and a raw file that contains the image data - do you have both in the same directory with the mhd header pointing to the data?

Comment: Dzenan, thank you for your answer! Now it's reading the file thanks to g.stevo clue (it was missing the raw file). However, now I don't know how to display the image... (I believe you can guess that I'm just a beginner =/)

Comment: Have you seen this: http://insightsoftwareconsortium.github.io/SimpleITK-Notebooks/

Comment: If the above notebooks don't help try googling "SimpleITK Python tutorial" and following something.

Comment: @g.stevo Your comment should be an answer, since that's what I missed in my case. All the best!

Answer (score 0):

MHD Files typically require an mhd header and a raw file that contains the image data - do you have both in the same directory with the mhd header pointing to the data?