# Medical Imaging Data - how to convert .raw/mhd to Nifti/nii

Tags: python, image-processing, nifti

Is there a way in Python or any other language to convert .raw/mhd image data to Nifti/nii?

I can load the .raw/mhd file in python via SimpleITK as in this post:
[Reading *.mhd/*.raw format in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37290631/reading-mhd-raw-format-in-python)

```
import skimage.io as io
img = io.imread('file.mhd', plugin='simpleitk')
```

I am having a hard time exporting as nii with proper dimensions... would ideally use the header information in the original mhd file...

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to just do in with SimpleITK.  You would do something like this:

```
import SimpleITK as sitk

img = sitk.ReadImage("input.mhd")
sitk.WriteImage(img, "output.nii")
```

If you don't have SimpleITK in python, installing it as follows:

> > pip install SimpleITK

SimpleITK does its best effort of preserving all header information, although it's not perfect. Hopefully the voxel dimensions will be preserved.

Comment: Is it possible to write a dicom series instead of a single dicom image ?

Comment: Yes, here is an example of how to write out a dicom series.  Most of the work is in getting the meta-data tags right.  https://simpleitk.readthedocs.io/en/master/link_DicomSeriesFromArray_docs.html