# Conversion of .mhd format to .nii format for multiple files code runs without error, but no conversion done

Tags: python, loops, image-preprocessing, nifti, medical-imaging

I am using the sliver07 dataset and my task is to convert.mhd format images to .nii format.
Following the answer of [Medical Imaging Data - how to convert .raw/mhd to Nifti/nii](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54271716/medical-imaging-data-how-to-convert-raw-mhd-to-nifti-nii), I was able to convert it for 1 image but now as I apply it for multiple images, it is not converting.

File module structure is this way:

- scan

  - file1.mhd
  - file2.mhd

My code:

```
import glob
my_path='/content/drive/MyDrive/Datasets/sliver07/sliver07-training-scans/scan/'
files=glob.glob(my_path+'*.mhd')

# Scan from train
import SimpleITK as sitk
out = '/content/drive/MyDrive/Datasets/sliver07/sliver07-training-scans/trial/'

for i in range(len(files)):
        img = sitk.ReadImage(files[i]) 
        sitk.WriteImage(img, out + files[i] + '.nii')
```

But the code is executing without error but conversion is not done yet. What must be wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it!
The path was wrong

```
# Scan from train
  import SimpleITK as sitk
   out = '/content/drive/MyDrive/Datasets/sliver07/sliver07-training-scans/trial/'

  for i in range(len(files)):
       img = sitk.ReadImage(files[i]) 
       sitk.WriteImage(img,  files[i].replace('.mhd','.nii'))
```